# curve movement animation in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, animation, bezier, curve, expression-blend-4

I use Blend 4 (storyboard) to create animation movement for a wisp. But now I was required to have the wisp move in curve path. I have found some solution in code (from programming windows phone 7 book) Part III chapter 2 XNA. However I just wonder if we can make curve movement by Blend 4 or any other easier way?

Answer (score 2):

Animation storyboards are the easiest way to go but if you're trying to animate along a complex path like a curvy line then the best way to go is to use the [PathListBox class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.expression.controls.pathlistbox%28v=expression.40%29.aspx) (MSDN).  The PathListBox class basically will let you easily animate an object along path no matter how crazy the path may be.

Here are some links for you to check out.

- [Creating a motion path with the PathListBox](http://www.microsoft.com/design/toolbox/tutorials/pathlistbox/motionpath.aspx) (from microsoft.com)
- [Silverlight 4 PathListBox for Motion Path Animation](http://www.andybeaulieu.com/Home/tabid/67/EntryID/195/Default.aspx)
- [Motion Path in Silverlight 4 using PathListBox](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=673)

Comment: Interesting! But we have to put the animation image inside the listBox?

Comment: My animation is an image, and I may have many wisp flying on the background of the page...

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how dynamic you want the animation. Using Blend, you can use [Storyboards](http://www.silverlightbuzz.com/2009/10/12/animating-with-storyboards-in-blend/) to create that type of animation very easily. The downside to storyboards is that they are quite limited in terms of flexibility. If the curves will always be the same, I recommend using the Storyboard approach. If you need a lot of flexibility in the animation (in real time), then you'll have to do it in code.

Comment: assume that the curves will always be the same, how can I do that?

Comment: Can you share the XAML for your curves?